# I ran the command ```do-release-upgrade``` on ubuntu20.04, it did not work I got an error that "No module named 'apt_pkg"

Tags: apt, 20.04, upgrade

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/do-release-upgrade", line 11, in <module>
    from UpdateManager.Core.MetaRelease import MetaReleaseCore
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UpdateManager/Core/MetaRelease.py", line 25, in <module>
    import apt
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'
```

Comment: Did you run it with 'sudo' ?

Comment: Looks like you changed the version of Python3. Return your 20.04 system to using Python 3.8, and `do-release-upgrade` will work again.